# SUM WITH CONDITION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query with clausule `SUM`. I need according to the sum of column.

Is this possible?

Does anyone have an example for me to look at?

My code below:

```
SELECT 
PL_MAT AS 'Código', 
RA_NOME AS 'Nome',
RJ_DESC AS 'Cargo',
SUM(PL_HORAS) AS 'Atrasos'
--SUM(PL_HORAS) AS 'Hora Extra' -- I need SUM this
FROM SPL020 
INNER JOIN SP9020 ON PL_PD = P9_CODIGO AND SP9020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND SPL020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
INNER JOIN SRA020 ON RA_MAT = PL_MAT AND SRA020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND RA_FILIAL = PL_FILIAL
INNER JOIN SRJ020 ON RJ_FUNCAO = RA_CODFUNC
WHERE PL_DATA BETWEEN '20120616' AND '20120715'
AND P9_CODIGO IN ('011','421','013','409')
--AND P9_CODIGO IN ('408','007','420','009','015','016','018') -- I need sum this 
AND RA_CODFUNC IN ('0408','1204','1233')--AUX COLETA C,MOTORISTA D,MOTORISTA CARRETEIRO
AND RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D','A')
AND PL_FILIAL = '05'
GROUP BY PL_MAT,RA_NOME,RA_ADMISSA,RA_CODFUNC,RJ_DESC,P9_DESC, PL_HORAS, P9_CODIGO
ORDER BY RA_NOME
```

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

```
sum(case when p9_codigo in ('408','007','420','009','015','016','018') then pl_horas else 0 end) as 'Hora Extra'
```

If you though put AND P9_CODIGO IN ('011','421','013','409') in the where clause the above ones will not be filtered.

So you will need to remove them differently.

I guess you will need it like:

```
sum(case when p9_codigo in ('011','421','013','409') then PL_HORAS else 0 end) as 'Atrasos',
sum(case when p9_codigo in ('408','007','420','009','015','016','018') then pl_horas else 0 end) as 'Hora Extra'
```

and remove the filters from the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Got it ! 
Thanks for all

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT PL_MAT AS 'Código', 
RA_NOME AS 'Nome',
RJ_DESC AS 'Cargo',
SUM(CASE WHEN P9_CODIGO IN ('082','080','030','409') THEN PL_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'Atrasos',
SUM(CASE WHEN P9_CODIGO IN ('408','007','420','009','015','016','018') THEN PL_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'Hora extra'
--SUM(PL_HORAS) AS 'Hora Extra' -- I need SUM this
FROM SPL020 
INNER JOIN SP9020 ON PL_PD = P9_CODIGO AND SP9020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND SPL020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
INNER JOIN SRA020 ON RA_MAT = PL_MAT AND SRA020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND RA_FILIAL = PL_FILIAL
INNER JOIN SRJ020 ON RJ_FUNCAO = RA_CODFUNC
WHERE PL_DATA BETWEEN '20120616' AND '20120715'
--AND P9_CODIGO IN ('011','421','013','409')
--AND P9_CODIGO IN ('408','007','420','009','015','016','018') -- I need sum this 
AND RA_CODFUNC IN ('0408','1204','1233')--AUX COLETA C,MOTORISTA D,MOTORISTA CARRETEIRO
AND RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D','A')
AND PL_FILIAL = '05'
AND RA_MAT = '000007'
GROUP BY PL_MAT, RA_NOME, RJ_DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

podés probar esto:

select nome, cargo, sum(Hora_Extra) as Hora_Extra 
from(
SELECT 
PL_MAT AS 'Codigo', 
RA_NOME AS 'Nome',
RJ_DESC AS 'Cargo',
SUM(PL_HORAS) AS 'Atrasos',

P9_CODIGO as 'Codigo'

FROM SPL020

INNER JOIN SP9020 ON PL_PD = P9_CODIGO

AND SP9020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'

AND SPL020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'

INNER JOIN SRA020 ON RA_MAT = PL_MAT AND SRA020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'

AND RA_FILIAL = PL_FILIAL

INNER JOIN SRJ020 ON RJ_FUNCAO = RA_CODFUNC

WHERE PL_DATA BETWEEN '20120616' AND '20120715'

AND P9_CODIGO IN ('011','421','013','409')

AND RA_CODFUNC IN ('0408','1204','1233')

AND RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D','A')

AND PL_FILIAL = '05'

GROUP BY PL_MAT,RA_NOME,RA_ADMISSA,RA_CODFUNC,RJ_DESC,P9_DESC, PL_HORAS, P9_CODIGO

) as kk

where Codigo in('408','007','420','009','015','016','018')
order by nome

Unos tips:
 no uses tildes (C"ó"digo)
 No uses espacios en los campos (Horas Extras)

Saludos